# How do I refer to a specific DataFrame in a spark pipeline?

Tags: r, apache-spark, pyspark, sparklyr

Suppose I have two spark DataFrames with the same features in Spark and I want to build a pipeline to cross validate them both. How can I refer to each table within a pipeline? I use `sparklyr` in R to do this, but I guess it should be the same with `pyspark`.

First I can use the following code to build a linear regression and cross evaluate it using `ml_cross_validator()`

```r
suppressMessages(library(sparklyr))
suppressMessages(library(tidyverse))
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")

copy_to(sc, mtcars, "mtcars")

mtcars <- tbl(sc, "mtcars")

pipeline <- ml_pipeline(sc) %>%
    ft_r_formula(mpg ~ .) %>%
    ml_linear_regression()

grid <- list(linear_regression = list(reg_param = 0))

cv <- ml_cross_validator(
    sc,
    estimator = pipeline, # use our pipeline to estimate the model
    estimator_param_maps = grid, # use the params in grid
    evaluator = ml_regression_evaluator(sc, metric_name = "rmse"),  # how to evaluate the CV
    num_folds = 2, # number of CV folds
    seed = 2018
)

cv_model <- ml_fit(cv, mtcars)

cv_model$avg_metrics_df
#>       rmse reg_param_1
#> 1 3.997882           0
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

But if I add another table with the same features:

```
mtcars_sample <- sdf_sample(mtcars, fraction = 0.8) %>%
    sdf_register("mtcars_sample")
```

How can I refer to it within the pipeline?

```
─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
 os       macOS Mojave 10.14.6        
 system   x86_64, darwin15.6.0        
 ui       RStudio                     
 language (EN)                        
 collate  en_US.UTF-8                 
 ctype    en_US.UTF-8                 
 tz       Europe/Stockholm            
 date     2019-09-13
```